# Block / disable the dialog box of beforeunload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for something that works on all browsers and OSs

Using this as a reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload

What I have so far

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
   var confirmationMessage = null;
   // do some ajax stuff // just setting a SESSION variable
   e.returnValue = confirmationMessage;
   return confirmationMessage;
});
```

It has been hard to troubleshoot since sometimes the event fires and sometimes not. Seems like I have to pause a bit before re-triggering.
The ways of firing the event that I am interested in are refresh and back button.

Safari seems to work but not Chrome or Firefox

Thanks for the ideas to come.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative you could store in the `localStorage` the data that needs to be synchronized with the session and when the user comes back to the page check if there is any data to sync with the server. You would need to clear the data from the `localStorage` after synchronizing.

Pros:

- It's synchronous
- Will work well in any modern browser

Cons:

- Might need you to ensure the sync is made before the app is loaded if it depends on this session variable

Comment: Never used localStorage but I did see it the browser preferences
The goal is to appended an iframe only once on the second return.
The iframe kinda triggers a script
Thanks @axelduch

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.

    var flag = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem( 'flag' ) );

    if( flag == null ){
        var flag = {};
        flag.yes = 0;
        localStorage.setItem( 'flag', JSON.stringify(flag) );
         
    }else if( flag.yes == 0 ){
        $('body').append('<iframe src="https://go.pardot.com/..” width="1" height="1"></iframe>');
        var flag = {};
        flag.yes = 1;
        localStorage.setItem( 'flag', JSON.stringify(flag) ); 
    }